# Joomla Multilanguage

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I created a website in Joomla 3.4, but the Multilanguage feature is just not working for me. I have followed the steps here:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/multi-lingual-joomla/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNI_B3RezgQ

I do not see the flags for my FaLang module and now I have an error about my menu.  (my site is salimlawfirm.com/en).

The Spanish site should be at salimlawfirm.com/es but this does not load the website. Instead shows me the root directory.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: @Lodder, I am getting:
Error loading Menus: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND falang_content.published=1 AND falang_content.reference_id IN(101,302,301' at line 4 SQL=SELECT falang_content.reference_field, falang_content.value, falang_content.reference_id, falang_content.original_value FROM r36x4_falang_content AS falang_content WHERE falang_content.language_id= AND falang_content.published=1 AND falang_content.reference_id IN(101,302,301,151,305) AND falang_content.reference_table='menu'

Comment: If you're getting an error with a 3rd party extension, first check to see that the extension is compatible with your version of Joomla, then contact the developer as it's their job to support you

Comment: i think you have a folder with name "es" in your root folder , please ensure this folder dose not exist

Comment: Thank you @Silverboy.ir! I deleted that folder and my website loaded correctly.

Comment: @Silverboy.ir - Please add this as a proper answer ;)

Comment: @Silverboy.ir, I deleted the folder it and it everything was working for a few days. Now the folder is back. It seems that a folder named "es" is being created in my root folder for whatever reason.  Any thoughts?

Comment: i have no idea why this folder created , but i think it must be because of a 3rd party application for joomla , change permission of root folder , then it must be fixed

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @Silverboy.ir.  I apologize, but I am not sure what you mean by permission of root folder. Could you expand a little bit? and thanks for the help!

Comment: ;) 
change permission of root folder to 0444 , this folder will be unwritable on linux and no one can create folder in this folder

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to get rid of that module/component, and use google translate instead. Google translate does a lot of the work for you and it's really easy to install.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give our component a try [Neno Translate](https://www.neno-translate.com) it has a bunch of features in addition to Falang.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to be very meticulous. The ostraining link tells you how to work with third parties module/compontents. But you can achieve a multi-language website in Joomla with no extra help.

1. Install the language packages you need
2. Activate the related language plugins if need be
3. Create a "main menu" (for example choose the type blog)per language where you set at list one item which is the home page of your website. Select the language of that item in the language dropdown
4. now you can create content, but set every time the language of the post.
5. Joomla has a build in language switcher module that you can use. set it. Now if you select a language, only the post of that language will show up in your home page. you will need to set a main menu module per language published in the same position as well.